# how to proceed to checkout page after making order in bigcommerce?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I have created orders using Bigcommerce API for a web based app.
Now after creating the order, how do I make the user to proceed to Bigcommerce checkout page to make the payment?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and please show what you had tried, so all here can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are capturing an order via the API, you won't be able to direct the user to a checkout page to just capture payments. The order creation is more for POS kind of flow, where you can capture the payment externally and create an order associated with that product in your bigcommerce store, thereby managing inventory details, syncing orders, etc.